# How do I do a jQuery scroll-to-stick menu smoothly?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have finally been able to get the header/navigation area to be a scroll-to-stick menu. The only problem I have now is when I scroll down the transition to making the header/navigation area stick is hard rather than a smooth fade in kind of transition like this site's navigation:

http://www.rodolphecelestin.com/

Their fade out is even smooth and nice. What snippet of code do I need to add to my code below (I'm not a coder. So if the code looks a mess - sorry, but it's what I got to work so far XD)?:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
      $el = $('#header'); 
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 480 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){ 
        $('#header').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
      }
      if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed'){
        $('#header').css({'position': 'relative', 'top': '0px'});
        $('#main-content').css({'margin': '30px 0px 30px'});
        $('#homepage-title').css({'margin-top': '30px'});
      }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That website actually has two menus. One fixed at the top and one which is stuck-to-scroll. I recommend doing the same, but if you still want to use the same menu I suggest adding

```
.css('opacity','0').animate({opacity:1},300);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rXM7N/1/

Comment: :D That worked perfectly! Thanks so much! That's exactly what I needed. Now I can stop messing around with the site's cosmetics. YAY!!! Thanks again.